# Allocate large array in PGI Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to allocate an real array finn_var(459,299,27,24,nspec) in Fortran. nspec = 24 works ok, while nspec = 25 not. No error message for allocation process, but print command print empty rather than zero values. If you use the array, there will be "segmentation fault" error message. The test program is

```
  program test

  implicit none

  integer                    :: nx, ny, nez, nt, nspec
  integer                    :: allocation_status
  real , allocatable         :: finn_var(:,:,:,:,:)

  nx    = 459
  ny    = 299
  nez   = 27
  nt    = 24
  nspec = 24

  allocate( finn_var(nx, ny, nez, nt, nspec), stat = allocation_status )
  if (allocation_status > 0) then
    print*, "Allocation error for finn_var"
    stop
  end if

  print*, finn_var

  end
```

Should not be the memory issue. I allocated double precision finn_var(459,299,27,24,24) without problem. What is the reason then?

I use pgf90 on linux server. the cat /proc/meminfo command:

```
MemTotal:     396191724 kB
MemFree:      66065188 kB
Buffers:        402388 kB
Cached:       274584600 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:       131679328 kB
Inactive:     191625200 kB
HighTotal:           0 kB
HighFree:            0 kB
LowTotal:     396191724 kB
LowFree:      66065188 kB
SwapTotal:    20971484 kB
SwapFree:     20971180 kB
Dirty:          605508 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:    48317148 kB
Mapped:         123328 kB
Slab:          6612824 kB
PageTables:     132920 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:  219067344 kB
Committed_AS: 53206972 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:    275624 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359462559 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

the unlimit -a command:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3153920
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3153920
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I compiled by pgf90. But if I compiled by gfortran, there is no problem.

Comment: Works fine here using gfortran 5.2 on a Mac.

Comment: the ‑Mlarge_arrays pgf90 compiler flag solves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't have to be insufficient memory. The size of the array is `2 223 304 200`. That is suspiciously close to the maximum 32bit integer `2 147 483 648`.

It looks like that the element count that the compiler uses internally overflows. The internal call to `malloc` requests not enough memory and then any attempt to read some of the elements at the end fails.

It is a limitation of the compiler in its default settings. It can be set-up to use 64bit addressing by using the option `‑Mlarge_arrays`.

See http://www.pgroup.com/products/freepgi/freepgi_ref/ch05.html#ArryIndex

Comment: That paragraph is about static arrays. The answer may be in a compiler switch, but mcmodel.

Comment: In the end, it is the -Mlarge_arays actually. It is however not clear from that page which treats a different problem (fitting static data in the data segment). The manual I referenced above describes more clearly what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is most likely a memory issue.

You array demands `459*299*27*24 * 4B` per `nspec` (assuming default `real` requires `4B` of memory). For `nspec == 24` this results in a memory requirement of approximately `7.95GiB`, while `nspec == 25` needs around `8.28GiB`.

I guess, your physical memory is limited to `8GiB` or some `ulimit` limits the amount of allowed memory for this process.