# Integer overflow when allocating large matrix in gfortran

Tags: arrays, windows, matrix, fortran, gfortran

I need to declare a matrix having 83000 rows and 83000 columns.
When I declare it in the following form:

```
double precision,allocatable :: MAT(:,:)
allocate(MAT(83000,83000))
```

compilation of the code by gfortran from MinGW 32-bit is successful, but when I run the *.exe, I receive the following error:

```
 integer overflow when calculating the amount of memory to allocate
```

If I change dimensions of matrix,  i.e. `(nrow=100,ncol=100)`, everything works, so the code seems to be correct.

My question is, how do I  declare matrix when its dimensions are big?

Comment: 83000 * 83000 is more than the maximum 32-bit integer value 2147483648. That is the reason for the overflow, the number of the elements is too large. However, the overflow does not happen on my computer, 64-byte integers are used for the sizes. Please tell us more about your Windows and gfortran. 32bit or 64bit? Which version? How do you compile?

Comment: If, by any chance, your system or compiler is 32-bit, than you are asking for too much memory anyway.

Comment: @VladimirF thx for your answer, I use MinGW (hence gfortran 32bit) under CodeBlocks enviroment (Windows 7 64 bit). How can I solve my problem? which you recommended compiler to use?

Comment: You must use a 64-bit compiler.

Comment: @VladimirF Intel Fortran Compiler 64 .. it's good ?

Comment: Any 64-bit compiler. If you have Intel, use Intel. But MinGW also exists in 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

The 32-bit compiler cannot treat such large arrays. 83000 * 83000 is more than the maximum 32-bit integer value 2147483648 so the size of the array cannot be computed. You must use a 64-bit compiler. (This overflow can happen even in some 64-bit compilers in default settings [Allocate large array in PGI Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174313/allocate-large-array-in-pgi-fortran) but gfortran should be fine.)

The matrix (56 GB) also by far exceeds the maximum amount of memory addressable by 32-bit processes.

Comment: I compiled with 64bit compilator, SilverFrost FTN95 64 bit, but I reveived e same error....

Comment: Which **exact** error? Link my note and link above, some compilers may need special flags to enable large arrays.

Comment: this is procedure with wich I compiled:
ftn95 file.f90 /64
SLINK64 file.obj /file:lol.exe

when I try to exute lol.exe, I obtain following error:
http://it.tinypic.com/r/2vdim1e/9

Comment: Try to use the `/64` flag during compilation.

Comment: So the error is quite different after all!!! Are you sure you have enough memory in your computer? You need 56 GB.

Comment: you're referring to RAM ?? :O Vladimir F

Comment: Yes, of course, I supposed you were aware about this.

Comment: I haven't this quantity of RAM, I think that I should find a different way to solve my problem, instead of create a big large matrix. Where do you read about the RAM requirements ?

However, you have been very clear about your answers, thanks... ;)

Comment: One element is 8 bytes. You have 83000x83000 = 6 899 000 000 elements. 6.9 G x 8 = 55.2 GB.