# Fortran relocation truncated to fit - mcmodel -fPIC not working

Tags: fortran, relocation

The makefile I attach comes from the source directory of a smooth particle hydrodynamics code. When I fix the number of particles to 128**3 particles, my code compiles fine. Now that I need to use 256**3 I get a `relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol ... defined in COMMON section in ...`.

I have tried several things I found online:

- using the set stacksize unlimited command
- adding the `-mcmodel=large` flag
- adding the `-fPIC` flag

none of these seem to work. I am also aware of the https://www.technovelty.org/c/relocation-truncated-to-fit-wtf.html article, but I do not understand what I am supposed to do.

My makefile: (I attach part of it)

```
include ../makeflags
CPP=g++  
CPPFLAGS = $(OPTIONS) -D$(SYS) -mcmodel=large -traceback

.SUFFIXES: .F

OBJ = hydra.o accel.o ahtime.o clist.o cool.o createcool.o dumpdata.o   

.f.o:
    $(F77) $(FLAGS) -c $<
.F.o:
    @ if test $(SYS) = ibm ; then \
    echo "$(CPP) -P -C $(CPPFLAGS) $< > tmp/$*.f";\
    $(CPP) -P -C $(CPPFLAGS) $< > tmp/$*.f;\
    echo "$(F77) $(FLAGS) -c tmp/$*.f";\
    $(F77) $(FLAGS) -c tmp/$*.f;\
        elif test $(SYS) = f2c ; then \
        echo "$(CPP) -P -C $(CPPFLAGS) $< > tmp/$*.f";\
        $(CPP) -P -C $(CPPFLAGS) $< > tmp/$*.f;\
        echo "$(F77) $(FLAGS) -c tmp/$*.f";\
        $(F77) $(FLAGS) -c tmp/$*.f;\
    else \
    echo "$(F77) $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<";\
    $(F77) $(FLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<;\
    fi

.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $<

hydra:  tmp $(OBJ) 
    echo $(FLAGS) 
    $(F77) -o hydra $(FLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)
    mv hydra $(RUNDIR)

new_options:
    touch *.F
    make

clean:
    /bin/rm  -rf *.o tmp 

system.o: system.$(SYS)
    @ if test $(SYS) = f2c ; then \
    cp system.f2c system.c; \
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) system.c; \
    else \
    cp system.$(SYS) system.f; \
    $(F77) $(FLAGS) -c system.f; \
    fi

tmp:    
    @ test -d $@ || mkdir $@
    @ for i in `ls *.inc` ; do \
    (cd tmp ; ln -s ../$$i $$i ) ; \
    done
```

My flags file: (I attach part of it)

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

# set SYS to one of: sun, dec, cray, sgi, ibm, hpux, f2c, g77
SYS = g77

# choose appropriate names for compilers
F77 = /usr/bin/f77
CC = cc
CPP = /lib/cpp 

# compilation flags for linux box
FLAGS= -O2
FLAGS=  -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -m486 
FLAGS= -Wall -g 
FLAGS= -mcmodel=large

# For cosmic test use
  UNITS_OPTIONS =
  OTHER_OPTIONS =

OPTIONS = $(FORCE_OPTIONS) $(UNITS_OPTIONS) $(OTHER_OPTIONS)
```

I understand this is some memory problem, which, for some reason is not resolved with the options I have described above. Please bare in mind I cannot mess with the variable definitions in the code (e.g. change COMMON blocks etc.), because they are linked to many programs and this will cause an overall failure of compilation. The exact error I am receiving is:

> /home/user/Downloads/Stage/hydra4.0/src/hydra.F:1:(.text+0x14): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `param_' defined in COMMON section in hydra.o

for many component programs, not only for `hydra.o`.

Comment: The most similar is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648934/fortran-relocation-truncated-to-fit-i-cant-create-big-arrays-on-server

Answer (score 0):

After 3 months of looking into this problem, I solved it by adding -mcmodel=medium.

Comment: One of the reasons might be you did not even tell us which Fortran compiler you were using. We could have pointed you to stuff like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174313/allocate-large-array-in-pgi-fortran

Comment: g77 as mentioned in my initial post.

Comment: I do not believe g77 has the `-Mlarge_arrays` flag. If you are calling `/usr/bin/f77` then it could be anything.

Comment: I just now noticed that -Mlarge_arrays was not taken into consideration by my compiler. So -mcmodel=medium did all the work.